# Why my implementation of sbrk system call does not work?

Tags: linux, malloc, system-calls, dynamic-memory-allocation, sbrk

I try to write a very simple os to better understand the basic principles. And I need to implement user-space malloc. So at first I want to implement and test it on my linux-machine.

At first I have implemented the sbrk() function by the following way

```
void* sbrk( int increment ) {
    return ( void* )syscall(__NR_brk, increment );
}
```

But this code does not work. Instead, when I use sbrk given by os, this works fine.

I have tryed to use another implementation of the sbrk()

```
static void *sbrk(signed increment)  
{  
    size_t newbrk;  
    static size_t oldbrk = 0;  
    static size_t curbrk = 0;  

    if (oldbrk == 0)  
        curbrk = oldbrk = brk(0);  

    if (increment == 0)  
        return (void *) curbrk;  

    newbrk = curbrk + increment;  

    if (brk(newbrk) == curbrk)  
        return (void *) -1;  

    oldbrk = curbrk;  
    curbrk = newbrk;  

    return (void *) oldbrk;  
}
```

sbrk invoked from this function

```
static Header *morecore(unsigned nu)  
{  
    char *cp;  
    Header *up;  

    if (nu < NALLOC)  
        nu = NALLOC;  

    cp = sbrk(nu * sizeof(Header));  
    if (cp == (char *) -1)  
        return NULL;  

    up = (Header *) cp;  
    up->s.size = nu;  // ***Segmentation fault
    free((void *)(up + 1));  

    return freep;  
}
```

This code also does not work, on the line (***) I get segmentation fault. 
Where is a problem ?

Thanks All. I have solved my problem using new implementation of the sbrk. The given code works fine.

```
void* __sbrk__(intptr_t increment)
 {
     void *new, *old = (void *)syscall(__NR_brk, 0);

     new = (void *)syscall(__NR_brk, ((uintptr_t)old) + increment);

     return (((uintptr_t)new) == (((uintptr_t)old) + increment)) ? old :
         (void *)-1;
 }
```

Comment: Interesting question, but you should probably expand on "doesn't work".

Comment: I have mentioned the cause of problem. Please see above.

Comment: Why do you try to "emulate" a syscall like `sbrk`? You should edit your question to motivate that.

Comment: I try to write a very simple os to better understand the basic principles. And I need to implement user-space malloc. So at first I want to implement and test it on my linux-machine.

Comment: Then, you don't need to define `sbrk` (you could use the system provided one). You need to use `mmap` in your  `malloc` and your kernel should have `mmap` or some equivalent way to change the address space. And you could run your OS under Qemu. BTW please *edit your question*, don't give important motivations only in comments!

Comment: Thanks for the very informative answers Mr. Basile. Please see above, already I have updated my question.

Comment: So I can't emulate the system calls, it's very important information for this case. Thanks All.

Comment: Thanks All. I have solved my problem using new implementation of the sbrk. The code given in the below in the question context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `sbrk` should probably have a `long increment`. And you forgot to handle errors (and set `errno`)

The second `sbrk` function does not change the [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) (as `sbrk` does). You could use `mmap` to change it (but using `mmap` instead of `sbrk` won't update the kernel's view of data segment end as `sbrk` does). You could use `cat /proc/1234/maps` to query the address space of process of pid 1234). or even read (e.g. with `fopen`&`fgets`) the `/proc/self/maps` from inside your program.

BTW, `sbrk` is obsolete (most malloc implementations use `mmap`), and by definition every [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) is executed by the kernel (for `sbrk` the *kernel* maintains the "data segment" limit!). So you cannot avoid the kernel, and I don't even understand why you want to emulate any system call. Almost by definition, **you cannot emulate syscalls** since they are the only way to interact with the kernel from a user application. From the user application, every syscall is an atomic elementary operation (done by a single `SYSENTER` machine instruction with appropriate contents in machine registers).

You could use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand the actual syscalls done by your running program.

BTW, the [GNU `libc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) is a [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). You could look into its source code. [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) is a simpler [libc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) and its code is more readable.

At last compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and use the `gdb` debugger (you can even query the registers, if you wanted to). Perhaps read the [x86/64-ABI specification](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf) and the [Linux Assembly HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/).